# Panel data - Keep companies which have at least 3 years of data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I am working with a df large panel data of financial related values, where I have many companies (and their fundamental values) across many years. 
The df looks something like this:

```
        year     ticker     return_y
0       1985      VLID       -0.5838
1       1985        KO        0.3245
2       1994       CTL       -0.3063
3       1996      DRYR       -0.1607
..       ...       ...           ...
1356    2002      CHUX       -0.2456
1357    1987       HRL       -0.0233
1358    2015        KO        0.2343
..       ...       ...           ...
56798   2017      AFMXF       0.0558
56799   2014        TER       0.0134
```

I know that some firms have only one or two years reported, and I am afraid that they will create some biases in my analysis. Therefore, I would only like to keep only those firms which have at least 3 years - can anyone help me find a way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take care of this in a single line: invoke the `groupby.filter()` with lambda:

```
df.groupby(df.ticker).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
```

Comment: This actually a more elegant way of achieving the same thing - thank you @dkritz

Answer (score 1):

There maybe a shorter way out there. My attempt;
Assumming there is one year per group, I would create a new column that numbers each group from 1 by chaining groupby to [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df['group']=df.groupby(['ticker']).cumcount()+1
df2=df[df['group']>=3]
df2
```

Find the maximum in each group and drop anything that has a maximum less than 3

```
df['group']=df.groupby(['ticker']).cumcount()+1
df['Max']=df.groupby('ticker')['group'].transform('max')
df[df['Max']>=3]
```

Comment: Happy to hear Tigio